# Is it possible to get page html content by url from angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get some url html content from angular
But all I get is **Cross-Origin Request Blocked**.

Here's the code I was trying to use.

```
this.http.get('http://www.google.com')
   .subscribe(
     data => {
       console.log(data);
     }
   );
```

I expect to find in the console

```
<html>
   ...
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
 import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

 const httpOptions = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({ =
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*" 
 })}; `

this.http.get('http://www.google.com', httpOptions )
```

or install extension `enable cors` for your browser

Comment: keep in mind the resource cors policy should allow this as well